# NullPointerException occurred while invoking getter method of a property

Tags: java, reflection, nullpointerexception, datasource, invoke

I'm trying to get properties of DataSource and Connection objects which are managed by JavaEE server(in this case I'm running WebSphere Application Server and Db2 as RDBMS).

I wrote following code.

```
public class ClassInfo {
    protected static final String NOT_APPLICABLE = "N/A";
    protected static final String UNKNOWN = "unkown";

    public static LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> getLinkedHashMap(Object obj) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String[]> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>();
        BeanInfo bi = null;
        PropertyDescriptor[] pd = null;
        String name, type, value, getter, setter;
        Method m;
        try {
            bi = Introspector.getBeanInfo(obj.getClass());
        } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pd = bi.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for (int i = 0; i < pd.length; i++) {
            name = pd[i].getName();
            type = pd[i].getPropertyType().getName();
            m = pd[i].getReadMethod();
            if (m != null) {
                getter = m.getName();
                try {
                    value= m.invoke(obj).toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Exception occured while procession " + m.getName() + " --- " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    value = UNKNOWN + " (getter is " + e.getMessage() + " )";
                }
            } else {
                getter = NOT_APPLICABLE;
                value = UNKNOWN + " (getter method is not available)";
            }
            m = pd[i].getWriteMethod();
            if (m != null) {
                setter = m.getName();
            } else {
                setter = NOT_APPLICABLE;
            }
            map.put(name, new String[] { type, getter, setter, value });
        }
    return map;
}
```

And here is my Servlet code.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/db2access");
LinkedHasMap<String, String> map = ClassInfo. getLinkedHashMap(ds);
... and more
```

I run this Servlet and got interesting output from my code.
There are property fields named "XADataSource", "active", "connection" (and more) and their getter methods named "isXADataSource()", "isActive()", "getConnection()" respectively.

"isXADataSource()" returned not null object and its value could be retrieved by "toString()".

NullPointerException occurred while this "isActive()" was invoked although I have checked that the Method object is not null. Here is the code block where this Exception actually caught.

```
m = pd[i].getReadMethod();
if(m != null) {
    getter = m.getName();              //not null
    value = m.invoke(obj).toString();  //throws NullPointerException
}
```

Here is stack trace log.

```
[2/4/18 8:33:59:281 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R Exception occured while procession isActive --- null
[2/4/18 8:33:59:282 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[2/4/18 8:33:59:283 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:283 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:284 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:284 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:284 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at net.mognet.servlet.ClassInfo.getLinkedHashMap(ClassInfo.java:35)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:285 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at net.mognet.servlet.ClassInfo.exposeAsMarkdown(ClassInfo.java:61)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:286 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at net.mognet.servlet.JDBCProperty.doGet(JDBCProperty.java:58)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:286 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:287 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:287 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:288 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:288 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:288 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:289 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1124)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:289 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:289 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:290 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:290 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:291 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:291 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:291 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:292 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:289)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:292 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1187)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:292 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:694)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:293 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:293 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:294 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:294 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:294 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:295 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:295 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:296 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:296 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:296 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[2/4/18 8:33:59:297 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.isActive(WSJdbcDataSource.java:1203)
[2/4/18 8:33:59:298 JST] 000000aa SystemErr     R   ... 33 more
```

I'm sure that the Method object(m) returned by "getReadMethod()" was not null but the Object returned by "m.invoke(obj)" was null. 
I assume that the property named "active" was not initialized(has null value) by JavaEE container and that made this happen. Is my assumption  correct? If not please tell me why this happened and how to resolve it.

I'm new to Java , so any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: You're calling methods on an internal WebSphere class, and asked why it returns an error? How about not calling internal method, or code defensively for exceptions, since you have no idea what those methods should be returning?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wanted to look inside the object that WebSphere generated. Its class is com.ibm thing. So I think I have to access its value via the method of the class.  And I know that "isValid()" returns boolean since the type could be retrieved by calling "getPropertyType().getName();".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets unpick this:

First of all, I assume that this code is in your `isActive` method.

```
m = pd[i].getReadMethod();
if(m != null) {
    getter = m.getName();              //not null
    value = m.invoke(obj).toString();  //throws NullPointerException
}
```

(If it isn't then you have shown us the wrong code ... 'cos the stacktrace clearly says that `isActive` threw the NPE.)

So assuming that the comments in the above are correct.

1. We know that `m` is not `null` at the statement `// not null`, and I will assume<sup>1</sup> that it is still not `null` at the next statement.
2. That means the call to `m.invoke(obj)` is not the cause of the NPE:

   - because `m` is not `null`, and
   - because if the NPE happened inside `invoke` for any reason, the stacktrace would be different.
3. It can't have been *inside* the `toString()` method because the stacktrace would be different.

So, by a process of elimination, the problem must be that `invoke` is *returning* `null` ... and the NPE is due to `null.toString()`.

So now you need to figure out how / why `invoke` returns `null`, and either fix the cause, or change your code to cope with that eventuality.

(The evidence doesn't point to a problem with `getReadMethod`.  It points to a problem with the method that you "got" and/or the target object for the method call.)

---

<sup>1 - This could be incorrect if `m` was a field rather than a local variable AND it was visible to other threads AND one of them happened to assign `null` to it at just the right instant.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And now I'm pretty sure that my assumption was correct. I'll add another answer to show that field object whose value is null cause this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your suggestions. Now I'm sure that the reason "invoke(m(obj)).toString()"(equals "isValid().toString()") caused NPE because *very simply* the field member was just null.

```
public class IntroSpectionTest {
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public IntroSpectionTest(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public String getA() { return a; }
    public String getB() { return b; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ClassInfo.getLinkedHashMap(new IntroSpectionTest(null, "String b").toString()));
    }
}
```

This code cause exactly the same situation.

I just wanted to take a look inside of the object that WebSphere generated but not about the code itself. Sorry for that if there is something misleading you.